Automatic deleteion of topic in Kafka
I have a kafka MSK cluster. Lots of field devices send messages to this kafka in their corresponding topics. Some may not send any messages for a long time. Since number of devices are growing, I would like to delete their corresponding topics and reclaim the resources. What can be the correct approach to solve this?

I'm not sure if this is the only or the best option, but I implemented it this way.
Since the cluster writes metrics, I always have information about how long the topic hasn't had any messages written. In my case, data shouldn't be constantly coming into the topic, so if the storage time is, say, several days, I filter out only those that have been empty for a month.
Then, I check each of these topics to make sure they are empty (in case something went wrong with the metric, and in general, an additional check never hurts, so to speak, a second factor).
If everything is ok, depending on the criticality of the topic (which in my case is simply marked via the script config. There are two considerations here - firstly, the verification scripts must correctly process all borderline cases so that there are no sudden problems, such as when the access timeout is not processed correctly and a decision is made that the topic is empty; secondly, if suddenly a month turns out to be too little, and it is critically important to save the offsets) - I can make a decision - to delete it immediately or send a message to monitoring that an empty topic was found (usually I send it if their number exceeds a certain value, this allows triggering alerts not too often) and then clean it up manually.
All this is wrapped either in a script via cron, or airflow dag or launched by a daemon, or via ci/cd - whichever is more convenient.

This is very helpful. At-least it confirms that it is not easy to solve. I am not marking this as an answer, as I am waiting for some ready-made scripts or easier solution to implement. If I don't get any better answer, I will mark his as an answer.
